# Trying to make an answer CW while answering-own-question makes question CW as well

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-wiki, self-answer

I was using the shiny new "answer own question simultaneously" feature to write [this post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange). I wanted the post to be CW, so I ticked the "community wiki" box, *under the answer*.

On saving, the entire post became CW. Now, that *was* my intention, but I expected *only the answer* to be CW (and then I'd have to use mod powers to CW-ify the post itself).

I tested it [again](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145/testing-stuff-qa-convert-to-cw-2/146#146) (will be deleted soon), since I wasn't sure exactly what I'd done, the same thing happened. Looking at the [revision history of the first one](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/141/revisions), one can confirm that the post was simultaneously made CW at the time of posting.

I, personally, don't think that this is by design. [CW *questions* are discouraged/have strict rules](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/), while answers are not. Wanting an answer to be CW *does not mean that you want the question to be CW as well*.

In fact, the mark-question-as-CW option has been removed (it's hidden away in the mod menu now), so I assume it's not something that's supposed to be really used.

Bug?

Update: Looks like this only happens to mods. I [tried it out](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3637/47255) on Programmers.SE, and the question was *not* converted. Makes this rather trivial since it only applies to mods and we can remove CW-ness anyway.

Comment: "Looks like this only happens to mods" This is possibly because you aren't normally able to ask CW questions anymore.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Yeah, probably.. The system must be silently rejecting it for non-mods.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas any reason why this is `[status-bydesign]`? CWness of an answer does _not_ imply CWness of a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only an issue that a moderator will face and as it is stated, mods can clear the ccwiki bit on a question if they desire.

Comment: Aah, I thought that that was the reason, wasn't sure. Thanks :)